# Integrated Angular, Express error handling

Tags: angularjs, express, angular-ui-router

I'm getting acquainted with the MEAN stack. So far, it's been a breeze pulling data from the backend with the all too familiar approach — use a service to make $http calls and assign the data returned to Angular controller scopes. Now I'm somewhat stuck, here's my Express code:

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.send({
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}
```

Then I set up Angular to render the view:

```
$routeProvider
  //...
  .otherwise({
    templateUrl: 'ui/error.html',
    controller: 'ErrorController'
  });
```

But, how do I pass the `err` object from Express to the Angular `ErrorController`'s scope?

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

On reading your question again, I'm not sure if I answered all parts of your query. There are a few open points here:

1. How are you invoking the server side API? If you're using $http, then you'd be using it inside your controller as follows:

   ```
   $http.get('/something')
       .success(function(data) { ... })
       .error(function(error) { ... }); // This is where you'll receive the error sent from the server
   ```
2. The following part (that I answered earlier) gives you a generic way to handle any errors while connecting your API from anywhere inside your Angular app.

---

You need to write an http intercepter where you can check the response' http status and/or body content and then use something like a $rootScope.emit() or simple alert() inside the responseError function to show the error. Here's a code snippet picked from angularjs documentation:

```
$provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function($q, dependency1, dependency2) {
  return {
    // optional method
    'request': function(config) {
      // do something on success
      return config;
    },

    // optional method
   'requestError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error
      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    },

    // optional method
    'response': function(response) {
      // do something on success
      return response;
    },

    // optional method
   'responseError': function(rejection) {
      // do something on error

      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
      // >>>>>>>> check for rejection.status here <<<<<<<<< //
      ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

      if (canRecover(rejection)) {
        return responseOrNewPromise
      }
      return $q.reject(rejection);
    }
  };
});

$httpProvider.interceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
```

Hope this helps!